# what range of values can a character variable hold in C?

Tags: c

I understand that character variable is declared like `char C;` in C. But what range of values can a character variable hold?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer really is: **It depends on your platform.**

Fortunately, this is all defined in your implementation's [`<limits.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html). Here you will find constants which define the valid range for a `char`, as well as all of the other standard data types.

A `char` is one byte, which is *usually* 8 bits. Technically, a `char` is `CHAR_BIT` bits. For some very old machines, this was 7, but these were before the C spec mandated that `CHAR_BIT >= 8`.  There are other implementations like DSPs that have larger `char`s.

- A `char` can take the range `CHAR_MIN` to`CHAR_MAX`
- A `signed char` can take the range `SCHAR_MIN` to `SCHAR_MAX`
- An `unsigned char` can take the range `0` to `UCHAR_MAX`
- If `CHAR_MIN == SCHAR_MIN`, then your `char` is signed; otherwise it is unsigned.

Answer (score 5):

According to the C Standard(N1570 Draft):

> 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types
>
> The values given below shall be replaced by constant expressions suitable for use in #if
>   preprocessing directives. Moreover, except for CHAR_BIT and MB_LEN_MAX, the
>   following shall be replaced by expressions that have the same type as would an
>   expression that is an object of the corresponding type converted according to the integer
>   promotions. **Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.**
>
> - — number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)
>
>   ```
>      CHAR_BIT     8
>   ```
> - — minimum value for an object of type signed char
>
>   ```
>      SCHAR_MIN    -127 // −(2^7 − 1)
>   ```
> - — maximum value for an object of type signed char
>
>   ```
>      SCHAR_MAX    +127 // 2^7 − 1
>   ```
> - — maximum value for an object of type unsigned char
>
>   ```
>      UCHAR_MAX    255 // 2^8 − 1
>   ```

the exact values for your implementation can be checked through the values defined in `<limits.h>`.

Comment: "Their implementation-defined values shall be equal *or greater* in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown.."